# Gradle uploadArchives task invoked for module even though explicitly not configured

Tags: gradle

I have a Java Gradle 2.14.1 project with a few subprojects: `a`, `b`, `c` and `no`. `no` is 'special' as it doesn't contain anything in `src/main/java`, it just has some e2e tests using all the modules. I want to apply the `maven` plugin to `a`, `b` and `c`, but not to `no`. Here is my code (in the form of a Bash session; please ignore the fact there is no code - it is the simplest thing which reproduces my issue):

```
maven-test $ find .
.
./a
./b
./build.gradle
./c
./gradle
./gradle/wrapper
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
./gradle.properties
./gradlew
./gradlew.bat
./no
./no/build.gradle
./settings.gradle

maven-test $ cat settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'maven-test'
include ':a'
include ':b'
include ':c'
include ':no'

maven-test $ cat build.gradle
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    if (it != project(':no')) {
        println 'applying maven for ' + it
        apply plugin: 'maven'

        uploadArchives {
            repositories {
                mavenDeployer {
                    repository(url: "file://build")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        println 'not applying maven for ' + it
    }

    defaultTasks = ['clean', 'build']

    afterEvaluate { project ->
        println("================ $project.path tasks:")
        project.tasks.each { task ->
            println("    $task.name")
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

maven-test $ cat no/build.gradle
jar.enabled = false
```

I.e. the `no/build.gradle` file disables the jar task (as there is nothing to jar). The main `build.gradle` file configures the `java` and `maven` plugins, but the `maven` plugin is explicitly omitted from the `no` module. Also, there is some debugging output added to see what is going on.

Here is the output (a bit chatty, I hope it is Ok):

```
maven-test $ ./gradlew clean uploadArchives
applying maven for project ':a'
applying maven for project ':b'
applying maven for project ':c'
not applying maven for project ':no'
================ :a tasks:
    assemble
    build
    buildDependents
    buildNeeded
    check
    classes
    clean
    compileJava
    compileTestJava
    install
    jar
    javadoc
    processResources
    processTestResources
    test
    testClasses
    uploadArchives
================ :b tasks:
    assemble
    build
    buildDependents
    buildNeeded
    check
    classes
    clean
    compileJava
    compileTestJava
    install
    jar
    javadoc
    processResources
    processTestResources
    test
    testClasses
    uploadArchives
================ :c tasks:
    assemble
    build
    buildDependents
    buildNeeded
    check
    classes
    clean
    compileJava
    compileTestJava
    install
    jar
    javadoc
    processResources
    processTestResources
    test
    testClasses
    uploadArchives
================ :no tasks:
    assemble
    build
    buildDependents
    buildNeeded
    check
    classes
    clean
    compileJava
    compileTestJava
    jar
    javadoc
    processResources
    processTestResources
    test
    testClasses
:a:clean
:b:clean
:c:clean
:no:clean
:a:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:a:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:a:classes UP-TO-DATE
:a:jar
:a:uploadArchives
:b:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:b:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:b:classes UP-TO-DATE
:b:jar
:b:uploadArchives
:c:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:c:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:c:classes UP-TO-DATE
:c:jar
:c:uploadArchives
:no:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:no:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:no:classes UP-TO-DATE
:no:jar SKIPPED
:no:uploadArchives FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':no:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Cannot publish artifact 'no.jar (com.test:no:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT)' (/Users/wujek/Development/IdeaProjects/maven-test/no/build/libs/no-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.145 secs
```

What is interesting is: the output says the `maven` plugin is not configured for the `no` module (`not applying maven for project :no`), the `uploadArchives` task is not listed for the `:no` module, but in the Gradle output is still says this task is invoked and it fails. I can also invoke this 'phantom' task directly using `./gradlew :no:uploadArchives` and it fails the same way instead of telling me the task is missing.

What is wrong with my configuration?